# Power BI DAX Cumulative Budget Starting at Zero

Tags: database, powerbi

I am trying to put together a visual for cumulative spend over time on a project. So far I have been able to get a chart based on actuals, but would like to have spend start at zero rather than the first transaction. Some details for context:

- 'Fusion Project Actuals' --> This table contains details on actual project transactions, with the following relevant variables:

  ```
  - 'Fusion Project Actuals'[Accounting Date] --> Gives the date for each specific transaction within a project
  - 'Fusion Project Actuals'[Amount] --> The amount of spend on each transaction for a specific project
  ```
- 'Fusion Project Details' --> This table gives project details primarily revolving around budget

  ```
   -'Fusion Project Details'[Project Start Date] --> This is the date a project was opened, BEFORE the first transaction ([Accounting Date]) (i.e., actual spend at this date is always zero)
  ```

For the visual, I created a measure to track cumulative spend based off [Amount] (X axis uses Accounting Date, Y axis uses Amount). The code for the measure is as follows:

```
  Cumulative Total Spend =

     VAR MaxDate = MAX('Fusion Project Actuals'[Accounting Date])
     VAR Result =
     CALCULATE(
     SUM('Fusion Project Actuals'[Amount]),
     'Fusion Project Actuals'[Accounting Date] <= MaxDate,
     ALL ('Fusion Project Actuals'[Accounting Date]))
     RETURN
     Result
```

---

The graph returns cumulative spend correctly, but I would like to have it begin with zero at [Project Start Date] on the x axis, rather than the first [Amount] at [Accounting Date]. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just add by UNION one additional row to your table 'Fusion Project Actuals', where 'Accounting Date = Project Start Date and [Amount] = 0 ?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? If not, then you'll need to modify the 'Fusion Project Actuals' tables to include a row with the project start date.